# Call C dll from Fortran

Tags: c, dll, fortran, call

I have created c dll and I want to call that c dll from FORTRAN f90 in visual studio 2019. Can anyone please help with a sample example.

I have tried the followed code.The code was build successfully, but while running, I GOT AN ERROR as displayed in the picture.

[image]

My fortran code

```
include 'MathLibrary.h'
program fortran
implicit none

print *, 'Max_size' , max_size

end program fortran
```

My MathLibrary.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef EXT_MYLIB
#ifdef DLL_BUILD
   #define EXT_MYLIB __declspec(dllexport)
 #else
#define EXT_MYLIB __declspec(dllimport)

#endif // DLL_BUILD

#endif // !EXT_MYLIB

 extern "C" int EXT_MYLIB max_size;
```

My MathLibrary.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MathLibrary.h"

int EXT_MYLIB max_size = 100;
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. You have to show the details about the DLL, at least the signature of the C function to be called and your current efforts and the problems and errors you encountered. There are many Fortran-C tutoruals on the web and many questions at this site, see the [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding] tag for many of these questions. Your question is currently too broad.  You have not even asked any actual question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have edited my problem

Comment: When you were uploading the picture, the website told you that you should not use it for code and error messages. It is important to copy the error message **as text** into your question so that other people with a similar problem can find your question.

Comment: After you copy the error message, you will also have to show the *exact* commands or configurations you use to build the code and the *exact* compiler versions you use for both C and Fortran. Can you build and run pure C programs? Can you build and run pure Fortran programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error message is either that you have selected the wrong project type in Visual Studio for the DLL or that you incorrectly named the DLL as the "Command" on the Debugging property page for the project.

If you are using Intel Visual Fortran, which seems likely, there are at least two worked examples of calling a C DLL from Fortran in the [Intel Parallel Studio XE for Windows Samples Bundle](https://software.intel.com/en-us/product-code-samples) under MixedLanguage.

Including a C file doesn't work for Fortran, and including anything before the PROGRAM statement does nothing useful.

You are looking to reference a C variable from a DLL. That gets a bit more complicated. In Fortran, a C global variable is interoperable with a COMMON block or a module variable. It's a bit easier to do it as a COMMON block, even though that's now deprecated in the language:

```
program test
use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
integer(C_INT) :: max_size
common /max_size/ max_size ! Same name, different entities
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLIMPORT :: /max_size/
print *, 'max_size', max_size
end
```

Or here's how to do it with a module variable. Note that you'll get a linker warning about a defined symbol being imported - you can ignore that:

```
module my_mod
use ISO_C_BINDING
integer(C_INT) :: max_size
bind(C,name="max_size") :: max_size
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLIMPORT :: max_size
end module my_mod
program test
use my_mod
print *, 'max_size', max_size
end
```

Your C DLL project needs to be separate from the Fortran executable project. They should be in the same Visual Studio solution and the Fortran project should depend on the C project (Right click on Fortran project and select Dependencies.) This will get the build order right, but because Visual C++ doesn't do output dependencies for DLL projects with non-C projects, you'll need to add the C project's .LIB as a source file for the Fortran project.